# Wordpress how to count sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, count

The code gives Output like:

```
1  
1
```

It doesn't give the correct answer.

```
    <?php

    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "select gemeinde, count(*) as total from gemeinde where gemeinde= 'Barsbek' ";
    $result = $wpdb->query($sql);
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean a "count query"? Do you mean, you need to count the result of a query?

Comment: Yes, i need to count the result of a query and would be better if the result would be stored in an array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure `sql` instead of `wp_query` then your code would be something like this:

```php
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT gemeinde FROM gemeinde WHERE gemeinde= 'Barsbek' ";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

echo $result->num_rows;
```

If you want your results in an array format then you could do something like this:

```php
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT gemeinde FROM gemeinde WHERE gemeinde= 'Barsbek' ";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A); // Notice you could pass ARRAY_A to get your results in array format
```